# Xcode autocompletion does not work for C++ libraries included via CMake

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I have an Objective-C based project with some C++ code. I have included library I want to use via CMake. However, Xcode autocompletion is not working properly for library's methods, classes and etc. 
Despite that, project compiles and there are no errors during build after inputting some of the library classes or functions in code. Xcode can also correctly specify the error, if I miss something like required parameters for method call (It will show up build error, telling which parameter I forgot to use). 
The problem is lack of autocompletion dramatically slows down the development and I need to fix it.

Comment: *Sigh* considering the fact that Xcode is essentially just another unix make with GUI on top of it, I would advice just switching to VSCode because the C++ plugin there is designed to work with this kind of stuff.

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg , seems like it is really the most effective solution

Comment: I would argue that this is a problem of CMake, in that it doesn't generate a suitable Xcode project with all references correctly setup. XCode is a proper IDE (unlike VSCode which as its base is nothing more than a text-editor). And if your workspace contains Objective-C projects or you're targeting IOS then your best environment is Xcode.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you suggest, in the same manner as it would a problem of  IntelliJ for not generating Eclipse configs? (Whatever that means)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the fact that Xcode is essentially just another UNIX `make` with GUI on top of it, I would advice just switching to VSCode because the C++ plugin there is designed to work with this kind of stuff.

In your case you could probably use some automatic cmake -> pbx generator if such tools even exist. Or, of course, do this manually, and configure the compilation out of an Xcode project.